# MySQL Query, GET(id)?!

Tags: php, mysql, icalendar

I have written the following script to creates a .ics file download based on a mySQL query.

```
$start = date('Ymd', strtotime($row['CourseStartDate']));
$end = date('Ymd', strtotime($row['CourseEndDate']));
header("Content-Type: text/Calendar");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=Bookings$id.ics");
echo "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
echo "PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 12.0 MIMEDIR//EN\n";
echo "VERSION:2.0\n";
echo "METHOD:PUBLISH\n";
echo "X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE\n";
echo "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
echo "CLASS:PUBLIC\n";
echo "CREATED:20091109T101015Z\n";
echo "DESCRIPTION:{$row['Attendees']}\n";
echo "DTEND:{$end}\n";
echo "DTSTAMP:20100109T093305Z\n";
echo "DTSTART:{$start}\n";
echo "LAST-MODIFIED:20091109T101015Z\n";
echo "LOCATION:{$row['CourseLocation']}\n";
echo "PRIORITY:5\n";
echo "SEQUENCE:0\n";
echo "SUMMARY:{$row['CourseTitle']}\n";
echo "TRANSP:OPAQUE\n";
echo "UID:".date('Ymd') . 'T' .date('His').rand();
echo "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY\n";
echo "X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1\n";
echo "X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE\n";
echo "X-MS-OLK-ALLOWEXTERNCHECK:TRUE\n";
echo "X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE\n";
echo "X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0\n";
echo "END:VEVENT\n";
echo "END:VCALENDAR\n";
```

mySQL

```
$sql = "SELECT BookingID, CourseStartDate, CourseEndDate, CourseTitle,(' ',Forenames,' ', Surname) as Attendees, LastUpdated
FROM Bookings
GROUP BY CourseStartDate, CourseTitle
ORDER BY CourseStartDate DESC";
```

When I download the file it creates a perfect calendar event with everything targeted as planned, however it only returns one course, I'd like to be able to do this on a course by course basis, i.e view a course and have the option to 'download to calendar' then run the script based on that course!?. I tried writing in an `if` statement but to no avail. Where am I going wrong?!

Comment: Wouldn't you just create multiple `VEVENT`s in a loop, inside your block of echo statements that generate the file? Your SQL (and we need the code that processes the query results, btw) should have the data you need, but you should be looping over the result set and filling `$row` with the data from each result, then writing it out to a new `VEVENT`.

Comment: Thanks @ShotgunNinja .. Sorry very new to php & mySQL queries. The courses are displayed on homepage of site by echoing out some of the `$sql` from above into a table
course date - coursename - add to calendar
another course date - another coursename - add to calendar
etc etc 
The `td` add to calendar is a button link to a file called caltest.php which is where I have written the VCALENDAR script. I want each of these buttons to run the script based on the course they are next too?! 
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you should :

Use $_GET to pass the id of your course.

Example if you are viewing "Course #1" :

```
<a href="caltest.php?id=$course_id">Download to calendar</a>
```

Then add WHERE clause in your SQL query in `caltest.php`  :

```
WHERE CourseId = $_GET['id']
```

Note : Verify that `$_GET['id']` is valid and use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for more security

Comment: Hi @user3198601 Thank you for your help, you have understood correctly! I've added the code to the link to now read `'<a href="/cal.php?id=' . $row['CourseDateID'] . '" target="_blank">Add to Calendar</a>'` and these are now added nicely to the end of the url when I hover over the 'add to cal' button. 
When I add the `$_GET` clause as a WHERE statement I get an error as it is affecting how the table is outputted, I think I need to put a variation of the WHERE statement into the VCALENDAR file perhaps as an `if` statement?! I've tried a few variations on this but non are working?!

Comment: Does the SQL query works but the result is wrong or does it throws an error with the `$_GET` ?

Comment: `$_GET` works & I can get the right `courseID` I just need to be able to tell the VCALENDAR that the queries such as `CourseTitle` `CourseStartDate` etc apply to the `courseID` that I have got?! Would a `foreach` loop do this?!

Comment: You don't need a `foreach` you can select only your course by using `WHERE CourseId = $_GET['id']`. Can you show us your table so we can help you writing the SQL.

Comment: Sure … `<?php 

require_once('calendar.php');

echo '<table class="bookings">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['CourseStartDate'] . '</td>' . '<td>' . $row['CourseTitle'] . '</td>'.'<td>' . '<a href="/cal.php?id=' . $row['CourseDateID'] . '" target="_blank">Add to Calendar</a>' .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

?>`

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT CourseDateID, CourseStartDate, CourseEndDate, CourseTitle, GROUP_CONCAT(' ',Forenames,' ', Surname) as Attendees, LastUpdated
FROM Bookings
GROUP BY CourseStartDate, CourseTitle
ORDER BY CourseStartDate DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die (mysql_error());`

Comment: `require_once('calendar.php');
//get the event id
 $event_id = $_GET['id'];
 $start = date('Ymd', strtotime($row['CourseStartDate']));
 $end = date('Ymd', strtotime($row['CourseEndDate']));
 //This is the most important coding.
 header("Content-Type: text/Calendar");
 header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=Bookings_$event_id.ics");`

Comment: `echo "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
 echo "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
 echo "CREATED:20091109T101015Z\n";
 echo "DESCRIPTION:{$row['Attendees']}\n";
 echo "DTEND:{$end}\n";
 echo "DTSTAMP:20100109T093305Z\n";
 echo "DTSTART:{$start}\n";
 echo "LAST-MODIFIED:20091109T101015Z\n";
 echo "LOCATION:{$row['CourseLocation']}\n";
 echo "PRIORITY:5\n";
 echo "SUMMARY:{$row['CourseTitle']}\n";
 echo "UID:".date('Ymd') . 'T' .date('His').rand();
 echo "END:VEVENT\n";
 echo "END:VCALENDAR\n";`

Comment: Can you simply try this in `caltest.php` `SELECT CourseStartDate, CourseEndDate, CourseTitle, CourseLocation, GROUP_CONCAT(' ',Forenames,' ', Surname) as Attendees FROM Bookings WHERE CourseDateID = $event_id`

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3`

Comment: How is your database structure then ? Are you trying to do that ? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd4720/1 (Run SQL)